# Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Tags: php, isset

```
if(isset($_GET['a'] or $_GET['b'])){
  echo "ok";
}else{
  echo "no";
 }
```

i have two var for one condition when isset $_GET['a']  or $_GET['b']
always echo ok either echo no

Comment: Should be `isset(…) or isset(…)`

Comment: Well the error message already says everything. What you probably want is (pseudo code): `isset(a) || isset(b)`

Comment: @mario Is it already bourbon time again :]?

Answer (score 0):

isset takes only one input not two

it should be

```
if(isset($_GET['a']) OR isset($_GET['b']))
{
echo 'ok';
}
else
{
echo 'nope';
}
```

Comment: try it there is always  echo 'nope'

Comment: i had missed a ' inside the a index. and the reason why its not working for you is because either $_GET['a'] or $_GET['b'] is not set. are these values in the url as parameters or are they post fields on the form?