# Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Tags: php, html, wordpress

When coding with `isset` i am getting an fatal error.I have searched stackoverflow but results are not satisfactory.

I am getting

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

**My codes are**

```
if (!isset( $size || $color )) {
    $style = '';    
}else{
    $style = 'font-size : ' . $size . ';color:' . $color;   
}
```

Comment: You're trying to do `$size || $color` and then see if that's set: use `if (!isset( $size ) || !isset( $color )) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isset expression error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205968/isset-expression-error) **or** [Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636880/compile-error-cannot-use-isset-on-the-result-of-an-expression) **or** [Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use “null !== expression” instead)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061024/fatal-error-cannot-use-isset-on-the-result-of-an-expression-you-can-use-nul)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (and the error message), you cannot pass the result of an expression to `isset`.

You can use multiple isset calls, or reverse the logic of your if/else block and pass multiple parameters to isset, which i think is the cleanest solution:

```
//true if both are set
if(isset($size, $color)) {
    $style = 'font-size : ' . $size . ';color:' . $color;
}else{
    $style = '';
}
```

You can clean this up a little further by setting the default value first, thus avoiding the need for an else section:

```
$style = '';
if(isset($size, $color)) {
    $style = 'font-size : ' . $size . ';color:' . $color;
}
```

You could even use a ternary, though some people find them harder to read:

```
$style = isset($size, $color) ? 'font-size : ' . $size . ';color:' . $color : '';
```

Answer (score 5):

you should use this way

```
if  (!isset( $size ) || !isset( $color ))  {
```

Comment: why donwvote without motivation .. the answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your expression always return either true or false => In theory isset always return true so PHP not allow this
Change

```
if (!isset( $size || $color )) {
```

To

```
if (!isset($size) || !isset($color)) {
```